# how to output random values from within an array contained in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
//how to output random values from within an array contained in an object?

var dog = {
        name: "Fluffy",
        leash: [true, false],

        randomizer: function() {
            this.leash[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.leash.length)];
            return this.leash;
            },

        call: function() {
            alert("Honey, " + this.name + " needs to pee…");
        },

        response: function() {
            alert("Ok, i got it, dear…");
            if (this.leash = false) {
                alert("You've got to put his leash on first");
            } else alert("Enjoy your walk…");
        },

    };
dog.randomizer();
dog.call();
dog.response();
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, i would like the alert in the response method to change based on a randomized boolean condition (leash: [true, false]).Thank you…

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you expect to get alert on or the other based on condition when you call `dog.response()` but you are always getting the same alert.

You can fix the issue in 2 ways

**Updating the object**

- In `randomizer`, set the value of the random value in a property and return the same property.
- In `response`, check for the value and show alert.

```js
var dog = {
        name: "Fluffy",
        leash: [true, false],

        randomizer: function() {
            this.leashed = this.leash[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.leash.length)];
            return this.leashed;
            },

        call: function() {
            alert("Honey, " + this.name + " needs to pee…");
        },

        response: function() {
            alert("Ok, i got it, dear…");
            if (!this.leashed) {
                alert("You've got to put his leash on first");
            } else alert("Enjoy your walk…");
        },

    };
dog.randomizer();
dog.call();
dog.response();
```

**Get value and pass it**

- In `randomizer`, get the random value return it.
- In `response`, pass the random value, check for the value and show alert.

```js
var dog = {
        name: "Fluffy",
        leash: [true, false],

        randomizer: function() {
            return this.leash[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.leash.length)];
            },

        call: function() {
            alert("Honey, " + this.name + " needs to pee…");
        },

        response: function(leashed) {
            alert("Ok, i got it, dear…");
            if (leashed) {
                alert("You've got to put his leash on first");
            } else alert("Enjoy your walk…");
        },

    };
let leash = dog.randomizer();
dog.call();
dog.response(leash);
```

Note, in original code there were some errors as well

- In `randomizer`, there is no LHS for `this.leash[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.leash.length)]`
- In `randomizer`, `this.leash` returns the array as against the expected some random value
- In `response`, `this.leash = false` is an assignment and not a comparison. For comparison, you will need to use `==` or `===`